# Issues with projection system in R (raster package)

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, extract

I'm new with GIS in R, and I'm facing a problem I really do not understand...

The aim is easy : I have dataset of GPS points (decimal) located on a Mediterranean island, and I want to extract Bioclim data for each point.

> ## My dataset looks like this
>
> loc

```
    code    municipality        x        y status balea
1   AHO1         Alghero 8.243606 40.61025      m   bal
2   AHO2         Alghero 8.175231 40.62431      m   bic
3   AHO3         Alghero 8.236722 40.61369      m   bal
4   AHO4         Alghero 8.236989 40.62351      m   bal
5   AHO5         Alghero 8.242231 40.61663      m   bal
6   AHO6         Alghero 8.239211 40.61161      m   bal
7   AHO7         Alghero 8.249450 40.61243      m   bal
8   ASI1    Porto Torres 8.305914 41.09242      m   bal
9   MAC1         Macomer 8.705692 40.24535      m   bal
10   MAD  Santulussurgiu 8.619711 40.16222      m   bal
11   MON       Montresta 8.526969 40.37630      m   bal
```

First, I create a map of Sardinia using function "map"

```
zone.etude <-map("world", regions="Italy:Sardinia", exact=TRUE,fill=T) 
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(zone.etude$names, ":"), function(x) x[1]) 
zone.etudeSpp <- map2SpatialPolygons(zone.etude, IDs=IDs, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
e <- extent(zone.etudeSpp)
```

Then, I create a raster stack with bicolor variables

```
for (i in 1:19) {
  r<-raster(paste("bio_",i,sep=""), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
  r.crop=crop(r, e)
  r.mask=mask(r.crop,zone.etudeSpp)
  assign(x=paste("r.crop_",i,sep=""),value=r.mask)
}
predictors=stack(r.crop_1,r.crop_2,r.crop_3,r.crop_4,r.crop_5,r.crop_6,r.crop_7,r.crop_8,r.crop_9,r.crop_10,r.crop_11,r.crop_12,r.crop_13,r.crop_14,r.crop_15,r.crop_16,r.crop_17,r.crop_18,r.crop_19)
projection(predictors) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
```

The issue appears now : when I use extract to get data for GPS points, the first 8 locations get NA...

```
val.bioclim = extract(predictors, loc[,3:4],cellnumbers=TRUE)

> val.bioclim
      cells bio_1 bio_2 bio_3 bio_4 bio_5 bio_6 bio_7 bio_8 bio_9 bio_10 bio_11
 [1,]   587    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
 [2,]   586    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
 [3,]   587    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA
```

Exactly as if they would "fall into the sea"... [I know 2 of them are out of the raster extent, as they come from small islets not included in Bioclim. But the remaining 6 are definitely far from shore]

So I decided to first check both projections

```
> proj4string(predictors)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> proj4string(zone.etudeSpp)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

They seem quite coherent, as they are all expressed in longlat and WGS84.

Then I made a map using plot, and that's where things went wrong

```
plot(predictors$bio_1)
plot(zone.etudeSpp, add = T)
points(loc[,3:4], pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
```

If I check the plot in my Rstudio window, everything looks OK, all point fall "inland" within the extent of the "predictor" raster, and the edge of both layer (predictors$bio1 and zone.etudeSpp are superposed)... but when I export 
the map in PDF, my points and zone.etudeSpp seems to be in the same projection, but are completely stretched toward N and S... which is not the case for the predictor plot. Thus I can see my 8 first points "falling into the sea".

[I'm struggling to add picture but I've screen shot if this to make it clearer... just don't know how to add them]

I'm quite lost,

- Is it a problem with CRS? I thought both maps and my GPS locations were expressed in the same system
- Is it a problem with my computer, or R version? I have updated all my packages this afternoon.

Guillaume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without example raster plus reproducible `loc` it's difficult to help you... But, try with:

```r
extract(predictors, SpatialPoints(cbind(x=loc$x,y=loc$y)),cellnumbers=TRUE)
```

An example:

```r
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10)

plot(r[[1]],xlim=c(6,9),ylim=c(40,42))
plot(SpatialPoints(cbind(x=seq(8.1,8.7,length.out = 10),y=seq(40.1,40.7,length.out = 10))),add=T)
```

[image]

```r
extract(r,SpatialPoints(cbind(x=seq(8.1,8.7,length.out = 10),y=seq(40.1,40.7,length.out = 10))),
        cellnumbers=T)
##        cells bio1 bio2 bio3 bio4 bio5 bio6 bio7 bio8 bio9 bio10 bio11 bio12 bio13 bio14 bio15 bio16 bio17 bio18 bio19
##  [1,] 646969   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
##  [2,] 646970   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
##  [3,] 644810   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
##  [4,] 644810   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
##  [5,] 642651  145   79   34 5428  280   48  232  122  216   218    81   772   129     5    59   334    42    61   295
##  [6,] 642651  145   79   34 5428  280   48  232  122  216   218    81   772   129     5    59   334    42    61   295
##  [7,] 642652  153   82   34 5450  289   53  236  130  224   226    88   718   121     5    60   315    38    58   274
##  [8,] 640492  150   81   34 5510  287   50  237  127  222   224    84   724   120     5    58   314    42    60   273
##  [9,] 640492  150   81   34 5510  287   50  237  127  222   224    84   724   120     5    58   314    42    60   273
## [10,] 638333  147   77   33 5518  281   49  232  123  218   221    81   718   114     7    56   304    47    63   267
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have checked and provided the coordinate system of `predictors` and `zone.etudeSpp`, instead of `loc`. This kind of error is possible to CRS differences. Check the `loc` CRS and reproject if its different (just doing `proj4string(loc) <- proj4string(predictors)` will not work, then use the function `spTransform`)